# Problem in my C++ function with vector size not increasing

Tags: c++, function, vector

In the following code, I am attempting to add elements to a vector of strings, ints, and doubles but when I output the vector's size, it never moves past 1. This leads me to believe it's not adding elements, but instead changing the first element?

```
// Need to show this for the code I'm having issues with
struct Store_Info{ // Stores all info for a given item
    string store_name;
    string location;
    // vector<string> = item | vector<int> = stock || vector<double> = price
    pair<pair<vector<string>, vector<int>>, vector<double>> item_stock_price;

    Store_Info() = default;
    Store_Info(string, string);

    string how_many(int);
};


void stock_info(vector<Store_Info> &stores, int n_stores){ // This is the code I need help with
    for (int i(0); i<n_stores; i++){
        string name; string loc;
        int counter(0);
        bool active(true);
        while(active){
            string line;
            std::getline (cin,line);
            if (line == "")
                active = false;
            else if (counter == 0){
                name = line;
                counter++;
            }
            else if (counter == 1){
                loc = line;
                stores[i] = Store_Info(name, loc);
                counter ++;
            }
            else{
                regex reg{R"((\w+),(\d+),\W(\d+.\d+))"}; // From professor's piazza post

                std::smatch m;
                std::regex_match(line, m, reg);
                Store_Info current_store = stores[i];
                pair itemStock = std::get<0>(current_store.item_stock_price);

                std::get<0>(itemStock).push_back(m[1].str()); // Defines item name
                std::get<1>(itemStock).push_back(std::stoi(m[2].str())); // Defines amount in stock
                std::get<1>(current_store.item_stock_price).push_back(std::stod(m[3].str())); // Defines price
                //cout << std::get<1>(current_store.item_stock_price).capacity();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if this is formatted poorly, this is my first post.
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

edit: Might be helpful to know what's being inputted..
Using standard input, the function reads in this:
(int) Stores:
(Name of a store)
(A location)
(item name),(quantity),$(price)

Ex.)
2 Stores:
Local Grocery
California
Apples,2,$1.20

Mall
Michigan
Pizza,3,$4.00
Cake,1,$10.45

Comment: This is probably off-topic here. But FWIW, you can't use `stores[i] = ...` to increase the size of a vector; that's for indexing into an *existing* element of the vector. To change the size, use `.push_back` (or `emplace_back` or `resize`). Tangentially, see https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/02/18/knightmare-of-initialization/

Comment: Please make a [mre]. There's too much code here that is irrelevant to the problem and you didn't post a full program that can be used to reproduce the problem. See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider to change you code to something like this.
Using nested pair's is way too confusing. Then at least use std::tuple.
Also you need to use reference to the struct and not its copy !

```
struct Item {
    string name; // Defines item name
    int amount; // Defines amount in stock
    double price; // Defines price
}

struct Store_Info { // Stores all info for a given item
    string store_name;
    string location;
    // vector<string> = item | vector<int> = stock | vector<double> = price
    vector<Item> items;

    Store_Info() = default;
    Store_Info(string, string);

    string how_many(int);
};

void stock_info(vector<Store_Info> &stores, int n_stores){ // This is the code I need help with
    for (int i(0); i<n_stores; i++){
        string name; string loc;
        int counter(0);
        bool active(true);
        while(active){
            string line;
            std::getline (cin,line);
            if (line == "")
                active = false;
            else if (counter == 0){
                name = line;
                counter++;
            }
            else if (counter == 1){
                loc = line;
                stores[i] = Store_Info(name, loc);
                counter ++;
            }
            else{
                regex reg{R"((\w+),(\d+),\W(\d+.\d+))"}; // From professor's piazza post

                std::smatch m;
                std::regex_match(line, m, reg);
                Store_Info &current_store = stores[i]; // need to be reference and not the copy !

                //                               item name |  amount               |  price
                current_store.items.emplace_back(m[1].str(), std::stoi(m[2].str()), std::stod(m[3].str()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure about other bugs or problems because this code is not run-able.

Comment: Oh my god the reference fixed the entire thing thank you so much! And sorry for the messy code, I'm still relatively new to programming. I will keep your formatting in mind!